# DataGridView Row Filter Where condition is = [SomeString] ~Anything~ [SomeString]

Tags: c#, datagridview, rowfilter

I have rowfilter from textbox input and here is how it looks like

```
var dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
            try
            {
                dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("KATBR like '%{0}%'", filterKatbr.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''")) + "AND " + string.Format("NAZIV like '%{0}%'", filterNaziv.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''"));
                dataGridView1.Refresh();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
```

It supports 2 textbox and filter from 2 textbox in same time but for now lets focus on one textbox. What i want to achieve is if i type in textbox something like this `Computer%Land`, it needs to filter me everything that must have `Computer` then any characterS between and then must have `Land` after it.

It doesn't matter what character is used for that `anything between`. I used `%` but it can be anything.

So if i had table like this:

```
|Computer432Land     |
|Computer321 Land    |
|Land 213 Computer   |
|Computer asd13  Land|
```

Result would be first, second and fourth column.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of your filter as a single statement, but instead as two statements to be joined.  That is, you need everything that:

1. *Starts with* "Computer"; **and**
2. *Ends with* "Land"

Like so:

```
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "ColumnName like 'Computer%' AND ColumnName like '%Land'";
```

As shown below, using your example data<sup>++</sup> we see the expected results.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("ColumnName", typeof(string));

dt.Rows.Add("Computer432Land");
dt.Rows.Add("Computer31 Land");
dt.Rows.Add("Land 213 Computer");
dt.Rows.Add("Computer asd13 Land");
dt.Rows.Add("Computer asd13");
dt.Rows.Add("asd13 Land");

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

[image: DataGridView screenshot only displaying rows containing the data "Computer432Land", "Computer31 Land", and "Computer asd13 Land"]

Comment: Oh i forgot to give example where it doesnt start or end with that string.
Exmp. `123Computer432Land12` (it shoud filter me this)

Answer (score 0):

Oh it was catchy because of splitting string but here is how i made it (it is working only with one '%')

```
string filterNazivStr = filterNaziv.Text;
if(filterNazivStr.ToLower().Contains('%'))
{
    int i= 0;
    string first = "";
    string second = "";
    Char separator = '%';
    String[] substrings = filterNazivStr.Split(separator);
    foreach (var substring in substrings)
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    first = substring;
                        break;
                case 1:
                    second = substring;
                        break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("NAZIV like '%{0}%'", first) + " AND " + string.Format("NAZIV like '%{0}%'", second);
    }
```